# How can i realize snapchat like tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, snapchat

I'm currently developing snapchat like interface which enables left scrolling only when user swiped on the tableview cell. (nothing happens if user just scroll left.)

user can move to chat room only when specify the tableview cell.

[image]

I've been developing this app by expanding UIScrollView to contain couples of UIViewController. But I'm not sure how I can realize the function like above. Thanks a lot!

Comment: havent used snapchat before. so you want a custom menu to popup once swiped right?

Comment: Nope not in that way. Just like other normal scroll view i want to scroll left to chat view(the photo above shows user is on the way to chat view). But it should be available only when user exactly swipe on a table view cell.

Comment: so. like a segue on swipe of a tableView?

Comment: Yes. But the chat view should be contained in the scroll view